# C++ Count INI values without having keys names

Tags: c++, ini

Assume that I have this ini file:

```
[Ranks]

John    = 0
David   = 0
Albert  = 3
Tommy   = 1
Cyrus   = 3
Adam    = 0
Sarah   = 1
Alecia  = 3
```

I want to count how much `0` ,`1` and `3` I have. It's easy when I have the names and check their values then count them, but how's this possible to count them when I don't have the names

I prefer to use just some simple WINAPI's rather than using any class or library
PS: I'm using MFC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any predefined function for such a rather specialized task.

And I don't see what difference it really makes whether you have the names of the entries to look for.

The basic algorithm is however really easy:

1. Create a `std::map<int, int>`, containing as key each value you are interested in, and as value a 0 (that will be the count of such values in the end)
2. Read each line of the file
3. If the line doesn't start with a `[` and contains a `=`

   1. extract the part between the `=` and line end.
   2. find the entry with the extracted part as key in the map
   3. increase the count for that key

Comment: Its shouldn't be an map<string, int> ?

Comment: I have a problem with this part "extract the part between the = and line end.", spliting an string was always a bad dream for me. I can use `wcstok` for spliting but I really don't like this way. Even MFC CString Class don't have an split function :|

Comment: Point 1 is rather pointless. Just do `myMap[key]++;`. That covers both 3.2 and 3.3. If a key was not in the map yet, on its first occurance it will be inserted, the associated value will be set to `int()`, i.e. zero, and finally that's incremented to one.

Comment: @MSalters with point 1 you could make the method only count specific values. if you want to generically count all values, then I agree, you don't have to do point 1 separately